# Google Translate to learn to read

Tags: google-translate

I am using Google Translate to get my child to play with letters. He thinks it is interesting to write a letter or a word and push "listen". The problem is that I always use CAPS lock, so he does not have to learn the lower-case letters, however, if I write something in the textbox with upper case letters and push "listen", this causes the voice to spell the letters, not read them. How can I solve that we can write upper-case letters, but still have Google Translate read the text, not spell it.

I am Norwegian, so I am not interested in alternatives, that does not support Norwegian pronunciation.

Answer (score 3):

Get something like [this keyboard with lower case letters printed on the keys](http://www.keyboardco.com/keyboard_details.asp?PRODUCT=466) so you don't have the problem of the mis-match between what he presses and what he sees on the screen. I don't know whether there is a Norwegian version of this or not.

Comment: This is a decent solution to the problem. I am, though, expecting to teach him the upper case letters first, as is customary. I will, however consider your solution if I cannot find one where he will work with upper case letters